# How to use servlets and jQuery+bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I have button:

```
<button id="saveFeed" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

in form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h1 class="modal-title">Edit feed name:</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" name="id" value="<c:out value="${feed.id}" />" />
                 <p>Enter feed name:</p>
            <input id="feedName" type="text" name="name"  value="<c:out value="${feed.name}" />" />
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button id="saveFeed" type="button" name="feedSub" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

script for jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $('#myInput').focus();
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#saveFeed').click(function() {
            var feedName = $('#feedName').val();
            var feedId = $('#id').val();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $.post('FeedController', {
                feedName : feedName,
                feedId : feedId
            }).done(function(data) {

            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    else if (req.getParameter("feedSub") != null) {
                String link = null;
                String name = req.getParameter("name");
                Integer id = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));

                feed = new Feed(id, link, name);

                feedDAO.update(feed);
            }

            resp.sendRedirect("FeedController?action=feedList");
}
```

I need to rename feed using jQuery but I am completely new to it. How to redirect to servlets handler button after save changes button was pressed using jQuery script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood your question, you're required to post the your feed data to the servlet by save button press, and update the existing feedName and Id value with jquery Ajax, isn't it?

if so, try this way:

1. Your HTML looks Ok, in the script use jquery Ajax call to your servlet:
   remove `value="<c:out value="${feed.name}"` as this will be updated by jquery ajax.

```js
    $("#saveFeed").click(function() {
     var feedName = $('#feedName').val();
     var feedId = $('#id').val();
     $('#myModal').modal('hide');
     va data= "feedName="+feedName+"&feedId="+feedId;
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "YOUR_SERVLET_NAME",
            data: data, 
            success: function(result) {
              if(typeof(result) !=='undefined'){
            //renaming the feedName 
            $('#feedName').val(result.feedName);
        }
            },
            error: function(error) {
             console.log("error" + error);
            }
        });
    });
```

2. And inside your servlet:

```js
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
throws ServletException, IOException {

  String link = null;
  String name = req.getParameter("feedName");
  String idVal = req.getParameter("feedId");
  Integer id = 0;
  PrintWriter out = null;
  Feed feed = null;
  try {
    //Avoid NumberFormatException
    if (idVal != null && !idVal.isEmpty()) {
      id = Integer.parseInt(idVal);
    }

    //your other stuff:
    //here I hope you have something like feed.setFeedName(feedName) where it prints the correct JSON value to the stream:
    feed = new Feed(id, link, name); 
    feedDAO.update(feed);


    //print response to stream:
    out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(feed);

    /* Or for better approach, use Gson and convert your 'feed' object and pass to stream: */


    //below line may not need since you use Ajax to update dynamically:
    //resp.sendRedirect("FeedController?action=feedList");

  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }


}
```

I didn't try running or compiling this code. just a guidance!
And couldn't format it properly so used as code snippets.

Comment: I assume form that appears after edit button was pressed is toggled by jQuery?Bootstrap just styles it? How to make appear div using jQuery if i want to avoid using bootstrap?

Comment: if you are looking for a way to show your div after some event happens, you can use $("#divId").show() inside a $.timeout() function. you need to make it hide initially.

Comment: What I am trying to solve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279465/how-to-use-servlets-and-jquerybottstrap-avoiding-bootstrap

Comment: 'result' attribute in the success{} block should already contains your feed properties. That is why we use Ajax. so I'm still not clear your issue here/there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78006/discussion-between-nomesh-desilva-and-ruslan-lomov).